# how to create menu on any other View in cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

how to create menu on any other View it mean's i m created a UIView and i want to add MenuButton  on it. This is my code but it is not working properly.. The UIView is hides the MuneButton..

```
    UIView *aview;
    aview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300,250)];
   aview.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:aview];


     // Standard method to create a button
     CCMenuItem *menuItem1 = [CCMenuItemImage 
                            itemFromNormalImage:@"Icon.png" selectedImage:@"Icon.png" 
                            target:self selector:@selector(NextButton:)];
    menuItem1.position = ccp(100, 60);
     CCMenu *starMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuItem1, nil];
      starMenu.position = CGPointZero;

[self addChild:starMenu];
```

and

```
     (void) NextButton: (CCMenuItem  *) menuItem
   {
NSLog(@"Button1");
    }
```

how to add Menu on UIView. I Try with AddSubview  removing addChild. And i try aview removing self..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it help to you..

```
 http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:index
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add a subview to a UIView, you are essentially adding them *on top of* the view. The cocos layer is always at the bottom. You can add the view to the root view controller, but you'll take a performance hit.

You're going about this in the wrong way anyway. Put your button in a CCLayer subclass with a CCColorLayer background and add that to your running scene. In your case: self.

Comment: i m  new in cocos2D so i have no idea how to create layer.can u explain in detail with sample code .

Answer (score 0):

My [Learn Cocos2D book](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/) (2nd Edition) has a chapter about UIKit integration that explains how you can place UIKit views in front of and behind the Cocos2D GL view while allowing all views (front views, cocos2d view, back views) to respond to touch events.